# Динамические url . Как лучше скрывать их?

Tags: php, seo

Доброго времени. 
Сайт имеет статичные страницы и перелинкован весь статичными . Но, если запрашивать динамические адреса в ручную, то также открываются те же страницы .

Хотелось бы уточнить пару вопросов на тему, что лучше :

1. делать редиректы на статические ?
2. при запросе динамических юрлов  выдавать 404?
3. использовать каноникалы?
4. закрывать от индексации ?
5. ваши варианты

Comment: А что значит "Динамичные" ? Какие-то от балды, или они что-то отображают определённый период времени? Если надо индексировать - то надо редиректить на урл для индексации. в любом случае 404 - если страницы как факта нету для того кто туда заходит. Редирект на статик не очень хорошо.

Comment: Нужно смотреть по конкретной ситуации. Если, например, это интернет-магазин с фильтрами и вы говорите про динамические с фильтрами - то лучше 301.
Вот пример - при попытке перейти по адресу, сгенерированному выбором фильтров
http://www.mebelok.com/uglovie-divany/filter-2-10_714_12/79-666/
Нас перекидывает 301 на "Единственно правильную страницу"
http://www.mebelok.com/uglovie-divany/filter-2-10_12_714/79-666/
В другом случае такая схема может не подойти

Answer (score 8):

Во главу угла нужно ставить удобство пользователя. Согласитесь, неприятно когда вы переходите по одной ссылке, а вас перебрасывают на другую. [Принцип наименьшего удивления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) в действии.

Учет удобства пользователя никак не мешает указать поисковиками какая же страница является исходной.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/path/to/page" />
```

Этот тег [поддерживает Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru) и [учитывает Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.xml#canonical).

Все это подразумевает что вы не можете совсем устранить возможность ручного выбора вот этих динамических страниц, например, потому что они уже где-то пролинкованы в сети. Если можете, то лучше чтобы их не было вовсе.

Comment: А вы часто замечаете, что произошёл серверный редирект? Я например, постоянно вбиваю в адресную  строку браузера sberbank.ru и не испытываю никакого дискомфорта, что меня перебрасывает на http://www.sberbank.ru/ru/person - да порой и этот адрес меняется с годами. Достаточно проверять, что сертификат принадлежит сбербанку, а там как хочет, так пусть и редиректит. Или даже домен целиком: gmail.com -> mail.google.com В общем, проблема надуманная. В части "ставить интересы пользователя выше интересов поисковиков" - никаких претензий, полностью соглашусь.

Comment: Проблема надуманная пока вы с ней ней сталкивались. Например, сайт одна очень большая японской компании при заходе *из поиска* на японскую страницу ([хоть такую](http://www.softbank.jp/mobile/price_plan/simulator/)) с английской локалью (`Accept-Language`) перебрасывал на главную страницу английской версии сайта. Считаете это круто и здорово так делать? (Вот сейчас проверил - одумались и исправили проблему.)

Answer (score 3):

Самое лучшее из предложенных вами вариантов -- это 301вый редирект (браузеры пользователей проходят по ним без проблем, поисковики редиректы не сохраняют в свой индекс).

Наихудший из вариантов -- это выдавать 404 ошибку, потому что вам нужно будет следить за  диапазонами IP-адресов поисковиков и юзер-агентами, а обычным пользователям показывать страницу. Вероятность ошибки очень большая, однако опытных клоакеров это никогда не останавливало... как и то, что у поисковиков всегда есть купленные диапазоны, которые они стараются не афишировать и юзер-агенты прикидываются обычными пользователями.

Закрытие от индексации через robots.txt - это способ раскрытия информации, а не сокрытия, его даже рассматривать нечего.

Канонические url - это неплохой вариант... для хорошего веб-мастера, который думает о пользователях, а не о поисковиках.

Что ещё из того, что вы не предложили можно добавить? Из пришедшего в голову по материалам searchengines.ru --  вы явно не думаете о том, что нужно для динамических страниц выключать метрики и аналитики, а то они "стучат" в поисковики.

Как-то так в общих чертах.

PS <strike>«Я девочка, я не хочу ничего решать, я хочу туфли и платье!»</strike> Я не хочу баунти, я согласен на один upvote и шляпу This is Fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Неплохо было бы написать о каком движке (CMS) идет речь. Если проблема в дублях страниц, когда на одну и ту же страницу ведут несколько url-адресов, то самый просто способ решения правки в robots.txt или rel-canonical (а лучше и то и другое). Встречается у всех популярных движков типа Wordpress, Joomla и подобных. Особенно в старых версиях движков.

Для примера, для старых версий Wordpress при и использовании ЧПУ было актуально прописывать:

- Disallow: */?
- Disallow: */feed
- Disallow: /?s=

Таким образом мы закрывали от индексации все ненужные url (фид, страницы поиска, динамические url) и оставили только ЧПУ. Если этого не сделать то поисковики проиндексируют кучу мусорных страниц, с дублированным контентом. Вместо реальных 100 страниц сайта будет проиндексировано гораздо больше, что само по себе обесценивает ценность страниц сайта, плодит лишнюю конкуренции между страницами внутри сайта и затрудняет продвижение сайта (например, вместо нужной страницы в поисковиках отображается ее дубль, а на нее нужно купить ссылки либо заказать рекламу, получается все последующие действия будут иметь меньшую отдачу).

Для того чтобы убедиться в своей правоте можно зарегистрировать в google-webmaster и посмотреть какие страницы находятся в индексе.

В принципе, можно делать 301 редирект для небольших сайтов для полного контроля, либо в рамках многостраничных сайтов для отдельных "прокачанных" и специально продвигаемых страниц.

Answer (score -1):

по пунктам и в контексте php (*есть и другие решения и выбор лучшего определяется критериями, которые в рамках задачи на момент написания ответа не определены*):

> 1) делать редиректы на статические ?
>
> 2) при запросе динамических юрлов выдавать 404?

решение для обоих пунктов в php это функция [header()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)

> 3) использовать каноникалы?

если есть дублирующие ссылки на одну и ту же страницу то использование rel=canonical - обязательно

> 4) закрывать от индексации ?

реализуется тегами noindex, nofollow

Ответ:на сколько я понял для поисковых систем важно чтобы пункты 3 и 4 были выполнены обязательно, а пункты 1 и 2 вы можете реализовывать или нет, на ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score -1):

Поисковые системы, обнаружив идентичный контент по разным адресам, начинают их группировать, а после определяет один из них как наиболее подходящий для ранжирования. Так появляется вероятность появления страниц с частотностью = 0. К примеру: Купить кровать в Киеве. На такую страницу будет уходить вес и краулинговый бюджет, а люди попросту не будут искать ее в Google;

большой расход краулингового бюджета на страницы, которые менее приоритетны в SEO-продвижении. Кроме того, у таких страниц появляется потенциальная опасность. Любой человек сможет к вашим GET-параметрам подставлять значения, генерируя вам дубли, которые могут положить сайт. А при статических урлах вы можете настроить корректную обработку 404-й ошибки.

Для фильтров и сортировок, как правило, нет смысла создавать статические адреса. Такие страницы удобнее оставить на динамических URL.
Сами фильтры закрывают от поисковых систем по статистическому префиксу, например, /filter/ или, если фильтр постоянный, переводят его в категории/подкатегории. Если это GET-параметры, то к ним добавляют одно правило, в  каноникал на эту же страницу, но без GET-параметра.

Статические адреса используются в основном для важных в продвижении страниц: главная, основные разделы, категории, подкатегории, записи в блоге.

Comment: никаким образом не является ответом. просто какие-то общие соображения («вода»), приведённые, подозреваю, лишь для упоминания ссылки, которую я удалил.